# Web API Developer Environment

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an on-prem EF6 Web API 2 project in a testing environment, and now I need to set up a developer environment. For now I'm limited to an on-prem, non CI/CD, single developer team. We'll eventually move over to an Azure, VSTS, CI, Windows 10 Enterprise Store environment.

My question is: Should I create a separate Dev Web API 2 project and copy/past/import my models and controllers into the Test environment project when I'm ready to move from Dev to Test? Or should I use one project file with multiple EF6 Context/Configuration migrations for both Dev and Test remote Web API's?

I could just use IIS Express for my separate Dev Web API 2 Project instead of having two remote web api's?

I'm concerned with ensuring that my Test Web API gets accurately updated when I release. If I go with the single project, multiple Context, and multiple remote Web API's path, then I can simply Add-Migration, Update-Database, and Publish to the correct entities depending on the environment which I'm targeting.

Thanks.

Comment: Source control and branches?

Comment: Bitbucket and Master/Dev branches.